# Create granular access control for Google Container Registry

Tags: permissions, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am new to using GCR.
My use case is that I want to grant `push only` access to a specific bucket of my project on the Google Container Registry (gcr).

I figured that I'll have to create a service account if I want to grant this access to multiple users and also create a specific role for the same.

I did manage to create a service account, let's say `test-service-account`, and also created a role for the same, let's sat `test-role`.

I provided the following permissions to the role:

- storage.bucket.create
- storage.bucket.get

I also applied this role to the `test-service-account`. But still when I log in to docker registry locally, using

```
cat keyfile.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

and try to push the image, I get `denied: Access denied.`

What am I missing?

Also, the current method will give the `test-service-account` access to all the buckets. Is there a way to provide access to a singular bucket?